# not able to show all records in my database

Tags: php, mysqli

i am testing my database by executing some **MySQLi** statements

in this case : i want to display all the records of 2 specefic rows (name,score)

i checked how to do such thing in `PHP` , and i did it

problem is , the page is not showing anything at all , (blank empty page)

**My code :**

```
<?php
$servername = "sql3.freesqldatabase.com";
$username = "MY USERNAME";
$password = "MY PASSWORD";
$dbname = "MY DBNAME";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT name,score FROM Scores");
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Name: " . $row["name"]. " " . $row["score"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

and , i executed the same query in `phpMyAdmin` Control Panel , and it worked

What have i done wrong ?

Comment: A blank page is often the sign that you've made a syntax error (or other error). Your environment is probably configured not to show PHP warnings/errors so you're getting an empty result.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and add some error checking to your SQL statements.

Comment: Add echos to display something on screen and see what is going on. For example, before "if ($result->num_rows > 0) {" add an echo to display "$result->num_rows".

Comment: @JayBlanchard Good idea *Sam!*

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php would have signaled the syntax error along with what @JayBlanchard said.

Comment: *"well ,what i can say .. i'll read the code character by character next time"* - Sure, but error checking during development would've avoided this question entirely; one that's similar to thousands already asked. Syntax errors are considered off-topic by Stack's standards.

Comment: *Mornin Ralph!* Every once in a while a blind squirrel does something with nuts and stuff @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Mornin' Sam!* - Yeah, well that blind squirrel may as well stay in its burrow. I'm not about to let it climb up my tree. @JayBlanchard *ouch*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
$sql = "SELECT name,score FROM Scores");
```

Should be

```
$sql = "SELECT name,score FROM Scores";
```

This syntax error will cause an error and your environment is likely suppressing errors/warnings.

Comment: well ,what i can say .. i'll read the code character by character next time

Comment: You don't have to read line by line if you perform error checking @GabourX